# How do I create a query which displays dots (....) after a certain number of characters within the field

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I would like to create a query on a field which after a certain number of characters adds/displays a number of dots to show the user that there is additional text to read. At the moment there is a syntax error using the following code in which it doesn't like the "Left" instruction:

```
X:IIF(len(description) > 5, Left(description, 5) & "....", description)
```

Note: "X" is what i am naming the field 'description' in my query screen in Access

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exact syntax for this problem is:

X:IIF(len(description) > 5; Left(description; 5) & "...."; description)

Thank you Hans for leading me in the right direction

Answer (score 2):

You can start with `Len()` to determine the length of the string value stored in your field.  Here is an Immediate window example which uses a variable as a stand-in for the field value:

```vb
my_field = "0123456789" ' 10 characters
? Len(my_field)
 10 
my_field = "012345678901234" ' 15 characters
? Len(my_field)
 15
```

Then you can use that length in an `IIf()` expression.  If the length of the string is greater than your cut-off number (14 in the following example), use `Left()` to retrieve a substring and append " ..." to that substring.  Otherwise return the entire string.

```vb
' my_field is still 012345678901234 (15 characters) at this point ...
? IIf(Len(my_field) > 14, Left(my_field, 10) & " ...", my_field)
0123456789 ...
' use the same expression with the shorter string ...
my_field = "0123456789" ' 10 characters
? IIf(Len(my_field) > 14, Left(my_field, 10) & " ...", my_field)
0123456789
' longest string which avoids the "..." is 14 characters ...
my_field = "01234567890123" ' 14 characters
? IIf(Len(my_field) > 14, Left(my_field, 10) & " ...", my_field)
01234567890123
```

You can use that approach in your query where *my_field* is actually the name of a text field in your data source.

Comment: Thank you Hans. I think i almost have it but i need to know where to write this..  Do i write this in the field name of the Access Query design view?? At the moment, I have this:  X:IF(len(tblMasterListOfEventsHistoryNotes)>25,left(tblMasterListOfEventsHistoryNotes,25)&"...",tblMasterListOfEventsHistoryNotes)

Comment: What is *tblMasterListOfEventsHistoryNotes*?  That looks to me like a table name; you need a **field name** there.

Comment: I would switch the query from Design to SQL View and enter the expression there.  Actually, either view should allow you to do it, but for moderately complex expressions I find SQL View more convenient.

Comment: The table i am using is a compilationof two tables and i named the fields that way to better understand where the data is coming from

Comment: In that case, what is displayed under the *X* column when you run the query?

Comment: Is my syntax correct?  Calling the field "X" is it correct to start with that If Statement??

Comment: Note: **IIf** not **IF** ... two **I** in `IIf()`

Comment: Syntax error :(   X:IIF(len(tblMasterListOfEventsHistoryNotes)>25,left(tblMasterListOfEventsHistoryNotes, 25)&"...",tblMasterListOfEventsHistoryNotes)

Comment: I copied that statement from your comment and pasted it into Immediate window.  There is something odd about the characters in the field name in your `Left` function.  Here is what I get as your statement text ... `left(tblMasterListOfEventsHistor??yNotes, 25)`

Comment: Hans, you almost had it only that i needed to put ";" in place of the ","